# Simple style! tag doesn't work in either Functional or Class Component in Yew.rs framework

Tags: web, rust, frameworks, webassembly, yew

This is a question related to the Rust reactive WASM framework.

Here is the code (putting the style! component within the view function of the class component produces the same error). This example is taken from the example page here (https://docs.rs/yew-style-in-rs/latest/yew_style_in_rs/)

```
use yew::prelude::*;
use yew_style_in_rs::*;

#[function_component]
pub fn Mdpages() -> Html {
    style! {
        let css = css! {r#"
            border: solid green 1px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;

            & > p {
                background: white;
            }
        "#};
    }
    html!{
            <div class={classes!(css)}>
                <p>{"compile time static css"}</p>
            </div>
    }
}
```

And here is the error -

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Classes: From<yew_style_in_rs::css::StyleId>` is not satisfied
  --> src/pages/mdpages.rs:22:34
   |
22 |             <div class={classes!(css)}>
   |                                  ^^^ the trait `From<yew_style_in_rs::css::StyleId>` is not implemented for `Classes`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Classes as From<&'static str>>
             <Classes as From<&Option<T>>>
             <Classes as From<&String>>
             <Classes as From<&[T]>>
             <Classes as From<Cow<'static, str>>>
             <Classes as From<Option<T>>>
             <Classes as From<String>>
             <Classes as From<Vec<T>>>
   = note: required for `yew_style_in_rs::css::StyleId` to implement `Into<Classes>`
note: required by a bound in `Classes::push`
  --> /Users/peterweyand/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/yew-0.20.0/src/html/classes.rs:58:20
   |
58 |     pub fn push<T: Into<Self>>(&mut self, class: T) {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Classes::push`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0423.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `yew_page` (lib) generated 4 warnings
error: could not compile `yew_page` due to 2 previous errors; 4 warnings emitted
2023-02-05T03:08:40.774108Z ERROR ❌ error
error from HTML pipeline

Caused by:
    0: error from asset pipeline
    1: error during cargo build execution
    2: cargo call returned a bad status
2023-02-05T03:08:40.774976Z  INFO  serving static assets at -> /
2023-02-05T03:08:40.775031Z  INFO  server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

This is as simple an example as I can make and I don't know why the error is occurring. I've found a workaround by including a hashmap of styles that I can import inside class components, but it's a bit clunky. Here is my Cargo.toml - maybe that's the issue, but I've imported yew_style_in_rs -

```
[package]
name = "yew_page"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
route = "0.2.0"
yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }
yew-router = "0.17.0"
reqwest = "0.11.14"
wasm-logger = "0.2.0"
log = "0.4.17"
gloo-net = "0.2.5"
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.33"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.83"
js-sys = "0.3.60"
yew-style-in-rs = "0.4.1"

[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3"
features = [
  "Headers",
  "Request",
  "RequestInit",
  "RequestMode",
  "Response",
  "Window",
  'HtmlCanvasElement',
  'WebGlBuffer',
  'WebGlProgram',
  'WebGlRenderingContext',
  'WebGlShader',
  'WebGlUniformLocation',
]

[[bin]]
name = "yew_page"
required-features = ["yew/csr"]
```

Here is the link to the github question - https://github.com/yewstack/yew/issues/3115

Answer (score 0):

I took a moment to clone the [yew-style-in-rs](https://github.com/MatchaChoco010/yew-style-in-rs) repository and verify the examples.
They appear to work, but depend on `yew = "0.19.3"`.
Trying to use `yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }` with minimal changes as required by the newer Yew api gave me errors similar to the ones you see.

I also opened [issues/10](https://github.com/MatchaChoco010/yew-style-in-rs/issues/10) there.

[futursolo](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/issues/3115#issuecomment-1418831145) also reports

> This is due to yew_styles_in_rs does not support Yew v0.20. yew_styles_in_rs needs to be upgraded to support Yew v0.20 or you need to use Yew v0.19 with yew_styles_in_rs.

So I suspect you probably need to do one of

1. use the older `yew = "0.19.3"`
2. wait until [yew-style-in-rs](https://github.com/MatchaChoco010/yew-style-in-rs) supports `yew = {version="0.20.0",features=["csr"]}`
3. figure out how to update [yew-style-in-rs](https://github.com/MatchaChoco010/yew-style-in-rs) (and submit a patch) or
4. don't use [yew-style-in-rs](https://github.com/MatchaChoco010/yew-style-in-rs) and just put your css in your own components

Looking at what this offers I'd probably do 4. and do my own css, but if I really liked this approach and I needed something asap I'd do 3. or 1.  If there's no rush I'd do 2.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me. I wasn't originally aware (not paying attention) that this wasn't maintained by the maintainers of yew (in part because `style!` looks similar to `html!`). Right now what I'm doing is using a hashmap to store the styles and reimport them, which is OK, but it will mean that I'll have to make my own monad-ish function to do dynamic css is which is kind of a pain.